# How to close Chrome window from the other application?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, winapi, inno-setup, delphi

In my app i need to close chrome during installation.

I found chrome unique names:
Chrome_WidgetWin_0
Chrome_WidgetWin_1
Chrome_OmniboxView
Chrome_AutocompleteEditView

```
 winHwnd := FindWindowByClassName('Chrome_WidgetWin_0');
if winHwnd <> 0 then
  retVal:=postmessage(winHwnd,16,0,0);//16 means WM_CLOSE
winHwnd := FindWindowByClassName('Chrome_WidgetWin_1');
if winHwnd <> 0 then
  retVal:=postmessage(winHwnd,16,0,0);
winHwnd := FindWindowByClassName('Chrome_OmniboxView');
if winHwnd <> 0 then
  retVal:=postmessage(winHwnd,16,0,0);
winHwnd := FindWindowByClassName('Chrome_AutocompleteEditView');
if winHwnd <> 0 then
  retVal:=postmessage(winHwnd,16,0,0);
```

But sometimes id doesn't close. Expecially when minimized.
postmessage returns true, however.
Is there a way to close Chrome?
Is there a way to check if Chrome is really closed by user for example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can enumerate all the running processes, and kill all "chrome.exe". Is that too rude?
If it is acceptable, check the following documents:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It's easy enough to translate. The function calls are just the same.

Comment: Never "just kill" processes without many warnings first. Often, the application can't or won't shut down cleanly without asking the user. It can also result in data loss or corruption.

Comment: Yes, i know. But that app sometimes doesn't recognize "gentle" close requests. So I check db and file operations to be finished and stop Chrome.
@Fuqiang_Jiang used some other way, cause i use delphi. But the main approach is the same.